# SwiftUI Spacer not working next to a Toggle inside a HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to have a `Toggle` with their content aligned to the right of the screen and I notice a `Spacer` doesn't work next to a `Toggle` inside a `HStack`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isOn = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack { // with or without the VStack doesn't work.
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Toggle(isOn: self.$isOn) {
                    Text("Remember me")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

but if I put the `Spacer` and the `Toggle` inside a `VStack` it works (but vertically).

Also if a put another `View` instead the `Toggle` with the `Spacer` inside a `HStack`, it works.

How can I make it work the `Spacer` and the `Toggle` inside the `HStack`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the `Spacer` to push the text to the right? If so, you could do this instead:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isOn = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack { // with or without the VStack doesn't work.
            HStack {
                Toggle(isOn: self.$isOn) {
                    Text("Remember me")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```